# Is there a significant performance penalty for calling a subroutine vs inline code?

Tags: performance, perl

Old school question - I don't know how efficient the running of Perl is.

I have a group of if/elsif/else statements that process lines of data for different data types that come in the report.
I find it easier to read and look at the code if I use subroutine calls instead of variable sized chunks of inline code.

Some older languages had significant penalties in handling the calls so that is was faster to include short routines inline rather than call them.
I do not need to pass variables with the call.  The line being read has all the data and the significant items are put in variables to be processed later.

Probably not a critical bit of knowledge to have but I try to make my programs efficient and be readable.
I already have the chain of ifs so that the most common ones are checked first.

I have written the code inline.  I have no way to actually measure how fast it runs.  Since it processes things every 15 minutes, I don't want to tie up the files anymore than necessary.

Comment: It's a relatively expensive op, yes. But that rarely matters.

Comment: [Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark) it

Comment: "_I do not need to pass variables with the call._" --- nothing at all?  What does that code work with?  If there is any one variable that that line of code needs to process, a line from a file, a flag-value ... than that still has to be passed in.  Can you show a simple example?

Comment: @zdim: closure variables, global variables and other side effects don't need to be passed in.

Comment: @LanX Yes ... but I doubt that their (realistic) code uses only that.  For one, why would one need to iterate if the code runs on a global variable?  If it were to rely on "seeing"  variables that are in scope, changing in each iteration, then that's bad practice and often actually a Very Bad idea.  So I'd like to hear it from them what they're doing... :)

Comment: @zdim: The OP said _"I have written the code inline"_ but  _"easier to read and look at the code if I use subroutine calls instead of variable sized chunks of inline code"_. So the easiest way to refactor that are anonymous subs in the same scope working on closure vars without passing arguments. IMHO preferably in a dispatch table.

Answer (score 6):

Perl sub calls have a lot more overhead than function calls in most programming languages, however it's still a relatively small amount of overhead compared to things like file IO, network accesses, etc. Unless you're calling a function many thousands of times, there's going to be little advantage to inlining it.

One thing you mentioned stands out to me:

> I do not need to pass variables with the call.

This actually gives you a significant optimization possibility.

Instead of calling your function which handles the line as `foo()`, call it as `&foo` (with an ampersand and no parentheses). When a function is called in that way, this is a signal to Perl that the function takes no parameters, so Perl will avoid setting up a new `@_` array as part of the call. This saves a bit of overhead.

(A side-effect is that the function will now be able to see its caller's `@_` array!)

Comment: Hmm, what you describe sounds a lot like the `goto &foo` mechanism. Maybe worth comparing.

Comment: @LanX, My past testing showed `goto &foo` to be slower than a normal call. Or at least slower than `&foo`. This was long ago. But the point is that the frame removal `goto` performs slows things down.

Comment: @ikegami, interesting I wouldn't expect that. Trying out all proposed  techniques and benchmarking them could prove an interesting "meditation" on perlmonks. (I replied before your update, that frame removal slows things down could be an explanation, i would have expected the other way round)

Comment: `goto &foo` is slower than a regular function call, but saves stack frames which is nice in deeply recursive functions. `&foo` is faster than a regular function call, by about 20–40%. Of course it's only saving time in the call itself — it doesn't make the function body run any faster.

Comment: Yes, the size of the function body matters of course, at some point the overhead of the call doesn't matter anymore. And AFAIR this happens quite soon. But that's anecdotal evidence and should of course be benchmarked...

Comment: ... Not sure how best to measure "size of body" and with which commands as a unit. Eg N scalars assignments?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very general question without concrete code, which can only be answered in general terms.

Yes function calls are relatively slow, but this only shows when you scale massively, like with `O(n^2)`++ complexity and/or recursive calls.

Normally improving the algorithm with standard mechanisms pays off far better than micro optimizing the calls.

For instance in your example using a ["dispatch table"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) `$call{$type}->()` instead of `if/elsif/else` chains sounds better,  `O(1)` vs `O(n)`

["Memoizing"](https://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize) also comes to mind to avoid repeated calls via cached results.

So **the first thing** that you should do, when in doubt is [benchmarking](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark).

For instance one major overhead beside the call itself and connected stack/frame mechanics is copying from `@_` and declaring/initializing variables, especially arrays.

So using common ["closure vars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) could prove to be much faster.

FWIW, contrary to your assumption are inlining and readablity not opposed to each other.

You can always use [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval#eval-EXPR) to construct complex code from smaller snippets. Text manipulation is Perl's forte after all.

There are also more comfortable "macro" mechanisms available on CPAN.

###### === update

Another technique I used in the past to avoid trivial functions are [`goto LABEL`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto#goto-LABEL) statements.

Especially in your scenario with `if/elsif/else` chains where the usual point of return for all snippets is a `END_LABEL:` behind the chain.

The advantage over inlining is that repeated snippets won't lead to bloated code, and this without noticeable performance penalty.

*Again* only use those techniques after the benchmarks prove them necessary!

Answer (score 3):

Perl's function calls are costly, comparatively. A good discussion of that has already been offered, but then ultimately you can [benchmark](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark).

Given that no specifics are given here's a *very* basic example, adjust and expand as suitable.  I only test a sub with arguments because I can't easily conjure realistic code, for which we wonder about the sub call overhead, without *any* arguments.<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $count = shift // 10e6;   # iterations; test code too simple for lesser no

sub has_caps {                               # very simple test code
    return $_[0] =~ /[A-Z]/;
}
   
my $str = join '', 'a'..'z', 'A', 'a'..'z';  # test string

#sub w_sub_noargs { }                        # a realistic example?

sub inline {                                 # "see" string from higher scope
    my $flag = $str =~ /[A-Z]/;
}

sub w_sub_args { 
    my $flag = has_caps($str);
}

die "Unequal! (", w_sub_args(), ' vs ', inline(), ")" 
    if w_sub_args() ne inline();

cmpthese( $count, {
    w_sub_args => sub { w_sub_args() },
    inline     => sub { inline() },
})
```

This prints

```
                Rate w_sub_args     inline
w_sub_args 2518892/s         --       -41%
inline     4273504/s        70%         --
```

on a quiet server, and a very similar ratio on an older desktop.

There is a difference, but this is a *lot* of runs, 10 million.  (The code is so light that for a lesser number of calls, even `1e6`, I get a warning `too few iterations for a reliable count`.)
So the difference per call is minuscule, `~0.16``μs` (`1/2518892 - 1/4273504`), and it does take a lot of calls even for a small saving in runtime (`~6` million calls for one second difference).

Note that simple code here emphasizes the overhead (even as starting the regex engine isn't all that cheap).  With more work in the sub the relative difference is lesser.  On the other hand, I never unpack the arguments above but directly use `$_[0]`, and that reduces the overhead. (But this is something one may want to do, for simple code with performance concerns.)

So put some realistic code in there, with a realistic number of iterations.   If there is indeed a way to write a function for it that doesn't need input<sup>†</sup> then just add it to the benchmark.

But, in short -- is it worth it? Just how many calls does the real code make, and what is a total runtime?  Saving milliseconds *may* matter but *microseconds* don't, not in a scripting language.

Keep in mind that making sure to compare (strictly) "apples to apples" in benchmarking can be tricky.  Thanks to ikegami for comments.

---

A few general benchmarking notes.

It's often more convenient to use `cmpthese( -$runfor, ... )`, where `$runfor` has the number of seconds to run the test for (a 3 or 10 is often plenty
jjjj).

It turns out that running the benchmark as

```
cmpthese( $count, {
    w_sub_args => \&w_sub_args,
    inline     => \&inline,
})
```

results in a *larger difference*, about 80%.  (We can do it here since the subs need no arguments.) Not a game changer, but if benchmark's own overhead affects results then it is more accurate to do it without that overhead.  (I though that results are computed *without* the overhead but perhaps not everything can be accounted for?)

---

<sup>†</sup>  What data would that code work with?

If the sub takes data from outside, via a a file or network or a socket or such, then that easily dwarfs a function call overhead, probably by order(s) of magnitude.

If it relies on data "seen" in its scope then that's in general bad practice and usually indeed a bad idea.  For one, it's prone to possibly subtle errors, specially as the code is tweaked later.

Comment: Note that `$_[0]` was used instead of `my $str = shift;`, which does save some time.

Comment: Use `cmpthese( $count, { w_sub_args => \&w_sub_args, inline => \&inline })` and you'll notice the difference is much bigger.

Comment: (I keep `$_[0]` as for simple code w/ performance concerns one may well want to avoid unpacking)

Comment: Thanks for comments, incorporated and discussed